# CAAnimation stops when scrolled out of bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have a custom activity indicator in the form of an infinitely rotating UIImageView.
And this this amazing activity indicator is placed inside a table cell.

The animation is achieved this way:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

At first, it work beautifully... But when the cell gets scrolled off the bounds of the table, the animation stops, and I have no idea how to reset it... /:

Please help...
Thanks so much in advance... :)

Answer (score 2):

**The reason** is animation for rotation.z key became nil when **prepareForReuse made its work** or **your application came into background mode.**

Consider to draw activity indicator by hands or try something like  https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios

**The approach below** activity indicator works and rolling fine inside scroll / cells / background mode

I tried rotation.z and something workarounds based on CAReplicationLayer - both failed in scroll / cells / background mode

[image: progressLayer look]

```
private func drawLoaderCircle() {

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: loaderViewCenter, radius: loaderCircleRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

    setupGrapes(endAngle: 310, path: path)
}

private func setupGrapes(endAngle: CGFloat, path: CGPath) {

    let step: CGFloat = 2
    var grapeAnimationDelay: CFTimeInterval = 0

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: endAngle, by: step) {

        let radians = i * .pi / 180

        let x = loaderViewCenter.x + loaderCircleRadius * cos(radians)
        let y = loaderViewCenter.y + loaderCircleRadius * sin(radians)

        let grapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        grapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleWidth + 0.2, height: circleWidth + 0.2)
        grapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        grapeLayer.cornerRadius = grapeLayer.frame.width / 2
        grapeLayer.backgroundColor = loaderColor.cgColor

        grapeAnimationDelay += Double(rotateDuration * Double(step) / 360)
        let rotateGrapeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        rotateGrapeAnimation.path = path
        rotateGrapeAnimation.beginTime = grapeAnimationDelay
        rotateGrapeAnimation.calculationMode = .linear
        rotateGrapeAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        rotateGrapeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateGrapeAnimation.duration = rotateDuration

        grapeLayer.add(rotateGrapeAnimation, forKey: nil)

        progressLayer.addSublayer(grapeLayer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this animation is removed when corresponding cell is reused. At least, I've got `animationDidStop` delegate's callback when I returned dequeued cell from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

The simplest workaround I can come up with:

Your table view data source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell && [cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CustomCellProtocol)])
    {
        [(id<CustomCellProtocol>)cell beforeDisplayed];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Your cell:

```
static NSString* const kSpinAnimationKey = @"SpinAnimation";

@interface CustomCell () <CustomCellProtocol>
@end

@implementation CustomCell

-(void)startSpinAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0];
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kSpinAnimationKey];
}

-(void)beforeDisplayed
{
    UIView* animatedView = self.contentView;
    if(![animatedView.layer animationForKey:kSpinAnimationKey])
    {
        [self startSpinAnimation];
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, there is a simpler way to do this without having to call anything from the datasource method. Simply call `startSpinAnimation` from the cell initializer method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and `prepareForReuse` (after calling super). Putting it in both of those places will start the animation automatically in every possible case.

Comment: Using `prepareForReuse` is a very good idea for animation's restoration. Although it doesn't do for cases when a cell is just a container and should be unaware of it's custom content view. So we can still use my solution (with some minor changes) when controller manages a content of container cell.

Comment: U did not notion bug with background mode. Actually with you approach we also need to subscribe on .applicationBecomeActive in each cell instance and restore animation